# how to Convert ajax call values in to C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am able to get the values in single string by using ajax-call but its returning [object Object]

```
public static object Details4(string selectedJobSheet)
    {

       foreach (var item in selectedJobSheet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

    }
```

when I am using Foreach Loop its returning Different Values ex:'1110'

Comment: Is whatever you are parsing back using AJAX serialised?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you are parsing using AJAX is an object that has been serialised.

Maybe try deserialising the string into an object using

```
JobSheet Example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobSheet>(selectedJobSheet);

public class JobSheet
{
    Email {get; set;} 
}
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: selectedJobSheet is a parameter how to call parameter in deserialied method

Comment: The first line of the code I posted converts the serialised parameter (selectedJobSheet) into an object. Your class should have the variables from your serialised parameter for example {
  'Email': 'james@example.com' then your JobSheet should contain Email {get; set;} }

Comment: Its returning a Exception:

Comment: Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'EBCheckDAL.OffDetails' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: Can you post the full string you are receiving in the selectedJobSheet parameter